# numpy.insert() invalid slice -- Trying to Insert NaN in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I know there are already lots of questions about this, but none of the answers I've seen have solved my problem. I have a pandas DataFrame with 10 columns for data, but on some rows I have just 9 columns-worth of data. For the rows with just 9 datapoints, I need the data to be in the last nine columns. My solution is to insert a NaN value in front of the length-9 arrays so that the data is pushed to the correct columns. But everything I've tried has thrown up errors!

(I'm trying to insert NaN into a numpy array that looks like this: `[6070000.0 6639000.0 15004000.0 15944000.0 8888000.0 9896000.0 22502500.0 23577000.0 14835500.0]`)

My current best guess:

```
a = np.array(a,dtype=float)
a = np.insert(a,np.nan,0)

**IndexError: invalid slice**
```

Any ideas about how I can get this doggone NaN into the array?

Comment: Read the [docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) of the function you're trying to use carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently attempting to insert `0` at index `np.nan`. Switch the args around:

```
a = np.insert(a, 0, np.nan)
```

Comment: I hate it when the answer is that simple. Thanks.